# В далеком 2014 году

Tags: грамотная-речь

**В далеком теперь уже 2001-м** (Вы робот?! // «Огонек», 2014).
Этот корректный оборот не вызывает вопроса, но вот увиденная фраза — **в далеком 2014 году** — заставляет спросить: какая же временная дистанция определяет уместность таких устойчивых конструкций со словами *год*, *столетие*?
(https://progorod76.ru/news/30924)

Comment: Благодарю всех редакторов. Отрихтовали.

Answer (score 3):

Время — понятие и абсолютное, и относительное одновременно.
Для планеты Земля история человечества (длиной в тысячелетия) — это пшик на фоне нескольких миллиардов лет. Для человека, испытывающего страдания, и один день — вечность.

Вот, можно сравнить:

*Мне без тебя каждый **час — с год**,

Если бы время мельчить, дробя...*
Н. Асеев. Простые строки

*Есть только **миг** между прошлым и будущим,

Именно он называется **жизнь**.*
Л. Дербенёв

Для высоких технологий и позапрошлый год — это далёкое далёко:
*Кстати, **уже в далеком 2008 году**, пытаясь выбрать лучший красноярский результат года в области нанотехнологий, я отмечал структуры из бора.*
[Красноярск научный **2010**: итоги года](http://newslab.ru/article/355159)

Интересно, что относительно далеким может быть не только прошлое, но и будущее:
[Взгляд из 1930-го в далёкий 21-й век](https://www.kramola.info/vesti/neobyknovennoe/vzglyad-iz-1930-go-v-dalyokiy-21-y-vek?page=45)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это ощущение субъективно. Если жить спокойной, скучной и обеспеченной жизнью, то и десять лет могут пройти незаметной однообразной чередой и восприниматься "как вчера". Но бывают ситуации, в которых "там год — за три, если Бог хранит", и, к сожалению, это редко означает благополучную жизнь. Возможно, автор публикации хотел таким образом обратить внимание на сложную судьбу тех людей.

Comment: Понятно, что всё относительно, и «это было как вчера» может сказать сегодня побывавший на  двух войнах старик.

Answer (score 1):

Первая мысль: ощущение времени субъективно, значит спорить не о чем. Но прочитав статью, я изменил свое мнение. Журналист рассказывает историю одной семьи и начинает ее словами: "В далеком 2014 году одна из многочисленных украинских семей покинули Юго-Восток своей страны и отправились в Россию". В данном контексте журналист просто излагает факт, а значит его слова должны отражать если не объективную реальность, то общепринятую точку зрения на ход времени, а она, согласитесь, состоит в том, что события четырехлетней давности не являются далеким прошлым.

Кстати, не думаю, что строчные буквы уместны в выражении "Юго-Восток своей страны", ведь в таком контексте это не название региона.

Comment: Маленькое это сочинение и заканчивается курьёзно, и начинается: в подзаголовке — пафосные слова «история жизни». В главном же (по теме вопроса) ответ принимается.

Comment: @shampar  Да уж, если воспринимать все дословно, то до переезда в Россию была не жизнь. Стук в дверь...
- Рабинович здесь живет?
- Нет, Рабинович здесь не живет.
- А вы кто?
- Я? Я - Рабинович!
- Так что ж вы говорите, что вы здесь не живете?
- Так разве ж это жизнь?